# Writing a Permutation as a product of Disjoint Cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations

How do i write a permutation as a product of disjoint cycles ?

[image]

I know that in order to determine a cycle we need to start with the smallest element and move on till the mapping points to itself.Then start with the next non repeating smallest element..But how to write this as a product of disjoint cycles?

Comment: I suppose it is worth mentioning that disjoint cycles commute, that is, may be multiplied in any order. Hence (4)(1532) is also a valid answer.

Comment: @A.Sh From the method i have described i got (1532)(4).Is this itself the way to get Disjoint cycles?

Comment: Well, yes, you do (always) end up with disjoint cycles by performing your algorithm. Also, if you do exactly as described, you will end up with (1532)(4), so you have done correctly. Since disjoint cycles are permutations that act on entirely different sets of elements, they can be applied in any order. Just mentioning it, in case you would encounter a similar situation in the future : )

Comment: @A.Sh okay.thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we note that writing it as a product of disjoint cycles means that each number appears only once throughout all of the cycles.

We see that $1\mapsto 5$, $5\mapsto 3$, $3\mapsto 2$, $2\mapsto 1$. So, we can express this in cycle notation as 
$$(1532).$$
Now, we see what is left over... well, that is just $4$, which is fixed by the permutation in question. So, the permutation can be written as

$$(1532)(4),\mbox{ or equivalently, just } (1532).$$

Comment: Thanks.As i have described in the question what i get by applying is (1532)(4) =>(1532).Is this itself the method to get disjoint cycles?

Comment: That's all you need to do :)

Comment: okay.. so if i use the method i described in the question ie: finding the smallest etc... i will get the product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: Yes, I mean, that's all I did above. Wasn't it?

Comment: Yeah...got it now

Comment: How to express this same permutation as the product of transpositions ?

Comment: Basically, you play a game with $(5 1 2 4 3)$. Your goal is to transform it into $(1 2 3 4 5)$, however you can only do this by swapping two numbers at a time. If you swap two numbers, $1$ and $3$ say, then you record it as $(13)$. At the end, you'll have a list of transpositions - their product is the original permutation.

Comment: Watch out for the order in which you multiply them. In some texts, they would want you to multiply them in the order opposite to that which you listed them. Check which order your text employs.

Comment: Thanks.How do you say that the goal is to transform (5 1 2 4 3) to (1  2 3 4 5)?

Comment: So, I swap 1 with 5 to give $(1 5 2 4 3)$, so I write $(1 5$). Then, I swap 3 with 5 to give $(1 3 2 4 5)$, so I write $(3 5$). We continue this process until we get $(1 2 3 4 5)$, and them we multiply out the list of transpositions together (double check the order of this multiplication with your text).

Answer (score 0):

$4$ is the only one invariant, while the others mingle among them, thus there are only two cycles
$$(1\,5\,3\,2)$$
It's customary not to write any singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You start with the first number than you go to the number with is under this number and so on until you get back to the start number...... In your case you start with 1 then go to 5 then to 3 to 2 and are back at one,.... So the first cycle is (1;5;2;3)

Then you look at the numbers which aren't in the first cycle e.g. 4 and do the same again.... ( you can, but you do not have to mention cycles with length 1 if it is known in which Sn the permutation is or it is otherwise clear how long the permutation is.)

Comment: okay.. so if i use the method i described in the question ie: finding the smallest etc... i will get the product of disjoint cycles?