# How to Write Permutation as the Product of Transpositions?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I have the following problem

[image]

I have asked the question here [Writing a Permutation as a product of Disjoint Cycles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469981/writing-a-permutation-as-a-product-of-disjoint-cycles) and got the answer.Now how can i write this same permutation as a product of Transpositions.I know how to express it as a product of disjoint cycles and i know a transposition is a cycle with 2 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you decompose into cycles first, all you need to do is express each cycle as a product of transpositions. There are various ways to do this, for example
$$ (1\,2\,3\,4\,\ldots\,n) = (1\,n)\cdots(1\,4)(1\,3)(1\,2) $$
or
$$ (1\,2\,3\,4\,\ldots\,n) = (1\,2)(2\,3)(3\,4)\cdots(n{-}1\;n) $$

Comment: Hmm... I expressed the permutation as the product of disjoint cycles (1532)(4) then what should i do?

Comment: @techno: As I wrote: "all you need to do is express each cycle as a product of permutations".

Comment: @techno represent each cycle as a product of transpositions and put them together

Comment: @Omnomnomnom well i dont know how to represent each cycle as a transposition.Noob here :)

Comment: @techno: I suggest that you read my answer, immediately above this comment thread. It will tell you how to represent a cycle as a product of transpositions.

Comment: I read that but i dont understand what n refers to is it the number of terms?

Comment: @techno: $n$ is the length of the cycle.

Comment: okay i have (1532)(4)=>(1532).I have 4 terms ie:n=4.In your first example you wrote (1n)(2n) etc ... .Where does this 1 come from.I mean is it from the cycle ? If yes dont i need the other terms in the cycle

Comment: @techno: The first construction for a 4-cycle has $$(1\,2\,3\,4)=(1\,4)(1\,3)(1\,2)$$ If you want to express a different 4-cycle than $(1\,2\,3\,4)$ just replace the numbers on both sides of the equation in a consistent way that makes the left-hand side be the cycle you want to express. In other words, you have _in general_ $$(a\,b\,c\,d)=(a\,d)(a\,c)(a\,b)$$ and if you set $a=1$, $b=5$, $c=3$, $d=2$, you will get the particular cycle you have there.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks.... but your last comment is not well formatted.Can you please reformat it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm +1 for being very nice.