# Proof of a simple permutation problem

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

Consider a set $S = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, use $\Sigma$ to denote all permutations of the set $S$. The ordered set $\sigma \in \Sigma$ is a permutation of $S$.

Define operators $G_i$ for $i= 1,\ldots, n-1$, such that $G_i(\sigma)$ swaps the the $i$-th number and ($i$+1)-th number in the ordered set $\sigma$.

$\textbf{Problem}:$ Let the ordered set $\sigma_0$ be $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, show that any permutation $\sigma \in \Sigma$ can be obtained via applying some sequence of $G_i$ to the set $\sigma_0$.

This is something very simple I encountered in my research. I can think of proving this using the idea of "bubble sort". However, as I an new to the field of combinatorics/group theory, I do not know a good system of notations to present the proof. I searched online and saw the Cauchy's two line notation, but still don't know how to apply it properly.
Any help or suggestion regarding the notations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See if [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470211/how-to-write-permutation-as-the-product-of-transpositions) combined with [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470211/how-to-write-permutation-as-the-product-of-transpositions) help.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I think you linked to the same question twice...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks; you’re absolutely right. Here’s the [correct second link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469981/writing-a-permutation-as-a-product-of-disjoint-cycles).

Comment: The question amounts to showing that the symmetric group $S_n$ can be generated by the transpositions $(1,2)$, $(2,3),\ldots,(n-1,n)$. Searching for that is sure to produce any number of nice proofs.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for the comment. Now I see how to use the notations to define the operators $G_i$. But How can I show that any permutation can be obtained through applying a sequence of $G_i = (i,i+1)$? Thank you again!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you so much, that solved my question. Thank you again!

Comment: @ScottGuan: You’re welcome; I’m glad that we could help.